# Is there a find command that shows the files from the current directory for which a certain user has read premissions?

Tags: shell, find

I am trying to learn `find` and got stuck when tried to find files (if there are any) from current directory that a user can print (so to which user has read permissions). Pretty much what this command does:

```
find / -type f -user whateverUser
```

Comment: The question should be about `find`, not `grep`, yes?

Comment: This question would benefit from some clarification.  Does that `find` command do exactly ("pretty much") what you want?  If so, why are you asking about `grep`?  If not, what do you need it to do that it doesn't do?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To do this using grep:

`ls -o` to list the current folder

`ls -o . */**` to list sub folder as well, but for each file show the full sub path

`ls -o */** | grep -v '^d'` to exclude directories in the list

To see which files 'you' can read, you can grep for the owner :

`ls -o . */** | grep -v '^d' | grep " $LOGNAME "`

A subtlety is that you can all read files that have group group level `r` permission, or all user level `r` permission.

To include the latter is easy:

`ls -o . */** | grep -v '^d' | egrep "( $LOGNAME |^.......r..)"`

To include files you can access via group permissions is a little more complex. Not tested so here goes:

```
GROUP_GREP=$( groups | sed 's/ /|/g' )

ls -l */** | grep -v '^d' | egrep "( $LOGNAME |^.......r..|$GROUP_GREP)"
```

Now, you might need to make refinements in the cases where the filename contains any grep search terms (e.g. the user name, or group names).

Comment: See [Why shouldn't parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).